# (Statistics) [Undergrad] Find the minimum of a function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, statistics

With 1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ n, and $w_i$ $\geq$ 0, 
find the minimum $u^{*}$ of the following function: $C(u) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}  w_i \cdot \left | \left |x_i - u  \right | \right |^{2}$

---

What I have done:

I think the minimum of this function is the value for which $C'(u) = 0$. 
I found $C'(u) = 0  \Longleftrightarrow -2\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \cdot \left | \left |x_i - u  \right | \right | = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \cdot \left | \left |x_i - u  \right | \right | = 0 $ 

And I am stuck there. 
Could someone help me a bit? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi ! You did not differentiate correctly your function C ;)

Comment: Are the $x_i$ and $u$ vectors, or scalars?

Comment: @Joe hey, thx for answering. $x$ and $w$ are vectors. $u$ is a real number.

Comment: Then, if $x_i$ and $u$ are real numbers, $|x_i - u|^2=(x_i-u)^2$, and the derivative of that term with respect to $u$ is $-2(x_i-u)$, without an absolute value.

Comment: @Joe Yup that's right, but then what about the minimum of the function? I recall the derivative of the function is the sum of -2(xi - u), so how do you get $u^{*}$?

Comment: You find the critical point(s) by finding where the derivative is zero, as you wrote. The you can do other tests to see if that is a minimum.